# MAUI disable android back button in a specific page

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android, maui

I created a dotnet MAUI app. for some pages there's a need to disable the back button of android.

I've found this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/transitioning-from-deprecated-onbackpressed-in-net-maui/)  but it only did it to the main page.
is there any way to disable it?

This is the page xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UI.Pages.ScreenPlacementSelectingPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
             Title="">

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False">
        </BackButtonBehavior>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <Grid x:Name="AbsolutLayout"
          VerticalOptions="Center"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
    >
        <Image
            x:Name="UIbackground"
            Aspect="Fill"
            Source="uibackground.png"
        />

        <Grid x:Name="gridLayout"
              RowDefinitions="*,Auto,Auto,*"
              ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto,Auto,*"
        >
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The linked code should work globally.  You can add specific logic to the handler to check the current page and respond accordingly

Comment: Is it just to disable the back button on a page you want? Or do you want that code from the link to work for you?

Comment: @PeterWessberg its just disabling the back button on the page. the code works but the back button behavior IsEnabled = 'false' dont.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is just to disable the back button you can override the `OnBackButtonPressed` on that page.

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    // Return true to prevent back button 
    return true;
}
```